# multiple Html.Attr on one tag in razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, view

how do i use multiple Html.Attr on one tag as follows in a razor view? this doesnt work.

```
<tr @Html.Attr("style", "color: #FF3D0D;")
 @Html.Atrr("data-item", Model.ItemNumber)>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you need a Html.Attr helper rather than just using: `<tr style="color: #FF3D0D" data-item="@Model.ItemNumber">`?

Comment: no,just want to use the helpers provided, is it possible?

Comment: it appears to be a custom one, it doesn't seem to like the data- tag though so i've done the following: @Html.Attr("style", "color: #FF3D0D;") data-item="@Model.ItemNumber"

Comment: Wow. Using a more verbose syntax for the sake of using helpers with no added benefit at all is way beyond me.

Comment: What do you mean by `it doesn't seem to like the data- tag`? Are you getting an error? Unexpected behavior? Where does this helper come from? How is it implemented? What's the purpose of this helper? I can't see any value in it.

Comment: Kind of surprised at everyone dinging the OP for their design choice, rather that pointing out the rather obvious typo!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the .Attr helper either, but just incase you copied the code directly from your view, there is a typo, you have @Html.Atrr which I'm guessing should be @Html.Attr for data-item

Answer (score 0):

So, it has come to this..

```
@Html.Atrr("data-item", Model.ItemNumber)
```

- VS -

```
data-item="@Model.ItemNumber"
```

Just one word: **don't**. Your markup AND every single human being on earth will benefit from the later much straight forward syntax. The HtmlHelper `Html.Atrr` doesn't help at all, no value.

Also, the following works for me:

```
<body @Html.Raw("data-test1=\"1\"") @Html.Raw("date-test2=\"2\"")>
```

.. and renders:

```
<body data-test1="1" date-test2="2">
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably should be using `@Html.Attr` and not `@Html.Atrr`... or, as others have pointed out, just writing the attributes explicitly.